# insert array to MySQL using php

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I am trying to insert an array into mysql. The structure of the array is

```
Array
(
[0] => Array 
    (
        [.id] => *1 
        [name] => vpn 
        [service] => pptp 
        [caller-id] => 
        [password] => vpn 
        [profile] => VPN 
        [routes] => 
        [limit-bytes-in] => 0 
        [limit-bytes-out] => 0 
        [last-logged-out] => mar/12/2016 22:20:26 
        [disabled] => false
    )
[1] => Array 
    (
        [.id] => *2 
        [name] => 123 
        [service] => pppoe 
        [caller-id] => 
        [password] => 123 
        [profile] => VPN 
        [routes] => 
        [limit-bytes-in] => 0 
        [limit-bytes-out] => 0 
        [last-logged-out] => apr/04/2016 15:46:41 
        [disabled] => false
    )
```

)

The code I've created my table with is

```
// sql to create table

$sql = "CREATE TABLE myusers (
id INT(1) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
Number VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,  
Name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
Service VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
Caller_id VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
Password VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,  
Profile VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
Limit_bytes_in VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,  
Limit_bytes_out VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
Last_logged_out VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,    
Disabled VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
reg_date TIMESTAMP)";
```

(The array above contain 2 users but it can be more than 2k users)

How can I insert all users from the array to myusers table with separated info for each user?

Comment: Where is the `insert` query? You can generate a single query inside a loop and execute it.

Comment: make table column name and array keys are same. then it will will be very easier to loop and insert bulk into database... try and show your code...

Comment: dear  – Sougata Bose and – Naga i m new in php !! what i want is the code to insert into myusers table !! how i can do it?

Comment: In that case you should check some tutorials first to learn.

Comment: @HamidSami Sorry Boss, We are not doing code writing service! Please find somewhere else to get it out.

Comment: Use `foreach` and run the `INSERT` query.

Comment: thanks for @Sougata Bose and @ Rama Lingam

Comment: its done by this code

Comment: if(is_array($ARRAY)){

    $sql = "INSERT INTO myusers (Name, Service, password) values ";

    $valuesArr = array();
    foreach($ARRAY as $row){

        $Num = (int) $row['.id'];
  $name = mysql_real_escape_string( $row['name'] );
        $service = mysql_real_escape_string( $row['service'] );
        $password = mysql_real_escape_string( $row['password'] );

        $valuesArr[] = "('$name', '$service', '$password')";
    }

    $sql .= implode(',', $valuesArr);

    mysql_query($sql) or exit(mysql_error()); 
}

Answer (score 0):

Use `foreach` for `INSERT` the array values.

```
 $sample_array = Array(Array(
            ".id" => "1","name" => "vpn" ,"service" => "pptp",
            "caller-id" => "", 
            "password" => "vpn", 
            "profile" => "VPN", 
            "routes" => "",
            "limit-bytes-in" => "0", 
            "limit-bytes-out" => "0", 
            "last-logged-out" => "mar/12/2016 22:20:26", 
            "disabled" => false
        ),
     Array 
        (
            ".id" => "2", 
            "name" => "123", 
            "service" => "pppoe",
            "caller-id" => "",
            "password" => "123", 
            "profile" => "VPN", 
            "routes" => "",
            "limit-bytes-in" => "0", 
            "limit-bytes-out" => "0", 
            "last-logged-out" => "apr/04/2016 15:46:41", 
            "disabled" => false
        ));

    foreach($sample_array as $sample_value)
    {
        //Make the INSERT Query
        INSERT INTO table_name(column_name1,column_name2,...) VALUES ("value1","value2",...);
    }
```

Comment: Use `array_filter()` in php. Ref: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php